# I can't see faces on my model in all modes

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode

I'm new to Blender and this community.
Sorry for bad English.
I created a model with Blender 2.78. When I finished (no texture, no animation, only a model with grey original starter color) I added smoke effect to see what happens. 
From that moment I can no longer see faces. Only vertices and edges in all modes. I have tried all options, all modes, all buttons but nothing. 
I can only see my model selected(orange lines) in each mode. I can select vertices, edges and faces but this last it's impossible to see.
Is it a bug? Must I redo all my model from the begining? Obviously don't answer me with a suggestion to try <kbd>h</kbd>,  <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>...

[image]

Comment: maybe in the Properties panel > Data > Display > Maximum Draw Type > Solid?

Comment: yes, was in Object panel>Display. very thanks u save my head to the wall

Comment: Hi. I attempted to correct some of the language in the question. I hope I did not change any of the meaning. If I did, please forgive me, and edit your question using the edit link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome @wiseman.

You must enable the draw type to texture.

See the image below:

[image]